# update_user_meta updates to a wrong ID

Tags: ajax, user-meta

**Background Problem**

The site I'm working right now uses custom front-end forms for content, terms and user editing and creation. Access to wp-admin is blocked for non administrator.

All of them uses basic wp_ajax functionality.

On the user editing form, the function updates the user data using `wp_update_user()` and saves the meta field using `update_user_meta()`.

Just now i found out that one of the saved meta field is saved to another user ID (mine, administrator) by someone else.

The code wasn't changed because it works, even after I updated the overwritten user meta, using the same function.

**Code**

Here is the stripped code that saves the meta field.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_edit-author', 'process_edit_author');

function process_edit_author() {

global $current_user;
if ( empty($_POST) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST[$current_user->user_login],'edit-author') ) {
    echo 'You targeted the right function, but sorry, your nonce did not verify.';
    die();
} else {


    $profile_upload = $_FILES['profile-picture'];

    if ($profile_upload['name'][0]) {
        $profile_picture = attach_uploads($profile_upload);
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'profile-picture', $profile_picture[0]);
    }

    wp_redirect($return);
    exit;

    die();
}
}
```

The `attach_uploads()` saves the uploaded file as attachment.
The first file attachment ID then is saved to the user meta.

**Analysist**

So far I can only tell that the image is uploaded by someone else's account, because the author of the attachment is not me.

**Need Help**

Does anyone have found this problem?
Where and how should I debug this problem?
How can I prevent this to happen again?

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's likely because you are using `$current_user->ID`, which always refers to the currently logged in user, or when "empty" object if not logged in (`ID == 0`). If you would like to update user meta on any other user you would have to supply the user ID of that user in the `$_POST` data as well.

Comment: Thank you @Simon, but I'm not really sure about it, especially since the function actually works (almost all the time that is).

Comment: Yes, it will work as long as you are not editing users other than yourself. See [this note](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user#Checking_Other_User_Attributes) in the `wp_get_current_user ()` documentation, it says `ID` is `0` when the user is not logged in. Perhaps other functions will temporarily overwrite the `$current_user` (though I doubt it). I would recommend you use a function such as [get_userdata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) instead and store user ID's as needed by your forms/update methods.